# InDesign GREP: not replacing the search

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I'm searching for a tab at every end of a word. Something like `\l\t` now I want to replace the tab with a space.

How can I **exchange the tab with a space without changing the word**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for 
`(?<=\w)\t`
and replace by a space (or `\s` )

FYI: This will strictly look for a tab placed after any word character.

Comment: Thanks! How is `(?<=\w)` exactly working? How would it look like if I'm searching for a tab ahead of a word character?

Comment: (?<=xxx)yyy Is a positive lookbehind pattern. yyy is what you want to catch (\t stands for tab) and xxx is what must be placed before it (\w stands for word character) . Only yyy will be replaced, not what is between the brackets.  \t(?=\w) would be the positive lookahead: it will catch tabs placed before any word character.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. But how could I find e.g. tabs ahead of a word? I've tried `\t(?<=\w)` – That isn't the right syntax, isn't it?

Comment: \t(?=\w) is what you need. But you don't neccesraly need to remember all those GREP patterns, you can use the search/replace window > GREP and click on the @ then Match. Finally choose between the suggested patterns. Just add the query after the =

Comment: @Malte The `<` is the bit that means ‘look **backwards**’, so if you're looking for things after a word, you don't want to include that. `(?=)` means look _ahead_; `(?<=)` means look _back_.